# Want to update/modify the value of key in shelve

Tags: python, python-2.7, shelve

I have a data (i.e `{'/domflight': 10, '/intlflight': 20}`) and want to modify the value of `'/domflight'` to `50`. Below is my code which I am trying to do but no luck.

```
import shelve
s = shelve.open('/tmp/test_shelf.db')
try:
        print s['key1']
        s['key1']['/domflight'] = 50
finally:
        s.close()

s = shelve.open('/tmp/test_shelf.db', writeback=True)
try:
        print s['key1']
finally:
        s.close()
```

Comment: Define 'no luck'? What happens, what did you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shelve cannot detect changes to nested mutable objects. Setting a key in a nested dictionary does not trigger a save.

Re-set the dictionary instead:

```
nested_dict = s['key1']
nested_dict['/domflight'] = 50
s['key1'] = nested_dict
```

It is the assignment back to `s['key1']` that triggers a save.

Technically, what happens is that `s` is a subclass of the `UserDict.DictMixin` class with a custom `__setitem__` method. Assigning directly to keys in the `s` object calls that method an the change is saved. But assigning to a mutable object that is *nested* under a key will not trigger a call to `__setitem__`, thus the change is not detected and nothing is saved.

This is [covered in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#shelve.open):

> Because of Python semantics, a shelf cannot know when a mutable persistent-dictionary entry is modified. By default modified objects are written *only* when assigned to the shelf (see [*Example*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#shelve-example)). If the optional *writeback* parameter is set to `True`, all entries accessed are also cached in memory, and written back on `sync()` and `close()`; this can make it handier to mutate mutable entries in the persistent dictionary, but, if many entries are accessed, it can consume vast amounts of memory for the cache, and it can make the close operation very slow since all accessed entries are written back (there is no way to determine which accessed entries are mutable, nor which ones were actually mutated).

Comment: thanks martijn, I read the entire documentation but not sure how i skipped this part.

Comment: np, unless you have been bitten by this before (the ZODB project created a custom mapping class for this very reason) it is easy to miss.